# Why does an empty ajax POST request have no content type?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Even when I explicitly set an ajax call's contentType, the server says there was no content-type if data is not set. I don't see that I'm required to in the [specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5), so why does this happen and how can I avoid sending a dummy payload?

I forgot to mention my backend uses the content-type to route the request. I could tell the backend not to expect a content-type, but I was looking for a way to avoid this.

Comment: Why do you need a content-type for an empty request? Does it make a differences?

Comment: @empiric my backend uses the content-type to help route requests. I suppose I can remove the requirement for the URIs that don't need a payload.

Comment: Either that or you could handle empty ajax requests as a simple http/rest request when it comes to routing. That depends on what these request should do on the backend.

Comment: @empiric I'm starting to think that the payload should probably just contain the data needed rather than the URI when using an idempotent method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because as you said, the content would be null in such a that request. So null could be anything and nothing.

Comment: This answers the first half of my question and makes sense, but is there a way to force the content-type other than sending a dummy payload?